# compiling docker on win64 using go

Tags: go, docker, boot2docker, win64

```
    C:\Go\src\pkg\github.com\docker\docker>go build
    # github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system
    pkg\system\meminfo_unsupported.go:6: undefined: ErrNotSupportedPlatform
    pkg\system\stat_unsupported.go:7: undefined: syscall.Stat_t
    pkg\system\stat_unsupported.go:12: undefined: syscall.Stat_t
    pkg\system\utimes_unsupported.go:8: undefined: ErrNotSupportedPlatform
    pkg\system\utimes_unsupported.go:12: undefined: ErrNotSupportedPlatform
    pkg\system\xattrs_unsupported.go:6: undefined: ErrNotSupportedPlatform
    pkg\system\xattrs_unsupported.go:10: undefined: ErrNotSupportedPlatform
     # github.com/docker/docker/pkg/term
    pkg\term\term.go:16: undefined: Termios
    # github.com/docker/libcontainer/devices
    ..\libcontainer\devices\devices.go:73: undefined: syscall.Stat_t
```

what am I missing is it syscal pkg which is not found 
any one else came with this

Comment: docker doesn't use the usual go build system. You should use the binary distributions, or dive into their Makefile, and build scripts to see what's going on.

Comment: their makefile already expects docker to be compiled it was compiled my some in a forum for boot2docker but I ran into same problem that some ran into

Comment: regardless, you can't build docker with `go build`. Their Makefile may bootstrap the build within docker, so you have to go further down the build chain. Look at the documentation for contributors or packagers.

Comment: You do know that only the docker client can run on windows? Running `go build` on just the client code *might* work, though client and server have to have matching api versions.

Comment: yes docker than interfaces with boot2docker but for now i want to be able to to do kitchen list on a docker kind of file and succeed at it

Comment: it is my strong advice for anyone who will try this to follow the directions to the last point especially the go directory to gopath because otherwise you would be stuck like me

Answer (score 0):

I havn't taken the time to try it out yet, but you probably want to read https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/compiling-docker-cli-on-windows/

Comment: once compiled how does one do tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 since docker deamon is not running

Comment: what you've built on windows is not the docker daemon, its only a client. So you need to do something like `docker -H tcp://linuxbox:2375` - or set the `DOCKER_HOST` env var

Comment: for those who are looking to use this tool you will have to change the version number from 1.16 to 1.15 manually by edditing couple of "common" files also you have to create ".docker" directory and put in it "ca.pem, cert.pem,key.pem" becouse of tls and then it will work and sing